# How to delete directory ' :q!'?

Tags: ls, rm, special-characters

Accidentally, i have got this directory created in my home,

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K 2012-09-06 07:27  :q!/
```

I want to remove this somehow. I have tried using escape characters in double quotes but no luck.
Is there any clean way to remove it ?

Comment: maybe you should stop using vim so much :)

Comment: I can delete it using `rmdir :q!` on my MacOSX using `bash` and `zsh` and without any escaping or quoting. I don't understand where you're failing. Can you show us the commands you're running and the error messages you're getting?

Comment: `ubuntu@gslabrails:~$ rmdir " :q!"
    >>-bash: !": event not found`

Comment: That may be a history expansion problem. `rmdir :q\!` should work then. What is the output of `echo $-`?

Comment: `ubuntu@gslabrails:~$ echo $-
>>himBH`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a history expansion problem. `rmdir \ :q\!` should work, `rmdir ' :q!'`, `rmdir " ":q!`, and `rmdir " ":q!`, too.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I used the context menu in my file browser to delete a folder with that name. Unless you don't have any GUI on your system, that should work. No history expansion problem.

Comment: I love this: the Gordian knot approach

Comment: Actually, I just prefer GUI anyway. I'm so unhackerlike :P

Answer (score 0):

It is always helpful to use `./` followed by the filename completion feature of bash.  It will automatically insert the required escape characters.